# How to set the JWT token from server

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, jwt, single-sign-on, saml

I have a product which is using Angular as Frontend and DRF as backend. It uses JWT tokens for authentication. Currently Im adding SAML SSO to the product, at the acs endpoint Im able to verify the saml response (IDP initiated) and verify the user. I have created JWT token against the user. Now how to send the JWT token when redirecting to the landing page of the angular application (When user was logging in with password, HTTP post request was send to verify the password, in the HTTP response the token was set). But now there is no request from UI, to send the token as response. I can't send JWT as query param in redirect request (security risk?). Suggest a way to set the token on the browser.

Comment: There are basically 4 options to store the token in the browser: local storage, session storage, cookies, memory. Each has it's advantages/disadvantages. I personally store in the local storage and send back to the server in the auth header (bearer). Of course on the server, I only allow the frontend site to communicate with the api. For further reading: https://medium.com/@kasperverhulst/secure-storage-of-oauth2-tokens-in-client-side-applications-and-spas-d5801f558d00

Comment: @derstauner — The code generating the JWT is (a) on a different origin and (b) server side so doubly doesn’t have access to the local storage for the Angular application.

Comment: I understand you, that you want to send the token back to the server for further requests from client. Did I misunterstand you?

Comment: @derstauner, I have figured out how to send the token back to the server for every call. But the problem is when JWT is created on server side, how do I send this to my angualr applicaton(to set it in local storage).

Comment: You might consider posting as hidden field and triggering submit onload... see here: https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html

Comment: Your server can then respond by setting an http-only cookie (make sure you prevent csrf), or setting local storage (make sure you prevent XSS).  Using a standard POST avoids sending a GET with sensitive information which can often be put in server logs. Only standard GETs and POSTs are allowed to be cross-origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to share tokens between applications

##### Senario

There are two applications, app **A**, and app **B**.

- App **A** is responsible for the authorization and authentication of users and providing tokens to users to use **A, B** apps
- App **B** is a standalone app that shares some data with authenticated users.
- App **B** relays on the App **A** to identify the users.
- App **B** does not have any login page or signup page!
- To access the App **B**, users must login through App **A**, then after successfull login, users are redirected to the landing page of App **B**

The question is how to provide **access tokens** to App **B**?

#### Solutions

1. Add tokens to redirect-URL query params.
2. Add user-identifier to redirect-url query params
3. Implement a login form that makes a request to App **A** to log in.
4. These are the only ways!

#### Security Concerns

###### HTTPS

- You can share tokens through url-query-params.

###### HTTP

- Do not share tokens through URL-query-params, use a **temporary** user-identifier instead.

Answer (score 0):

in the generally you have some way to authenticate users by JWT:

1- use local storage: is not safe way because XSS attack.

2- use cookie: when you use cookie the cookie will be set in each header of your
request and all requests will be authenticate for backend. if you use cookie to
authenticate with JWT you have to use CSRF Token in your request to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking for best practices for storing the JWT token in your frontend after receiving it as a receiving it in your http response, correct? The other posts here have already covered the various pros and cons of the storage options (e.g. local storage, session storage, cookies, memory), so I won't go into that. So instead of covering where to store it, I'll cover best practice on how I to store it.

You mentioned you're using Angular framework, in that case, I'd put the logic in my frontend authentication store service. This also gives you the option of emitting the token as an observable, like this:

```js
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  BehaviorSubject,
  catchError,
  map,
  Observable,
  shareReplay,
  tap,
} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class AuthStoreService {
  private readonly baseUrl = `add-your-path-here`;
  private readonly subject = new BehaviorSubject < UserSubject > (null);

  user$: Observable < UserSubject > = this.subject.asObservable();
  isLoggedIn$: Observable < boolean > ;
  isLoggedOut$: Observable < boolean > ;

  constructor(
    private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
    private readonly errorService: ErrorService
  ) {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.user$.pipe(map((user) => !!user));
    this.isLoggedOut$ = this.isLoggedIn$.pipe(map((isLoggedIn) => !isLoggedIn));
    const currentUser: string | null = localStorage.getItem('auth_data_token');
    if (currentUser !== null) {
      this.subject.next(JSON.parse(currentUser) as UserSubject);
    }
  }

  login(user: UserModel): Observable < {
    user: UserModel
  } > {
    return this.httpClient
      .post < {
        user: UserModel
      } > (`${this.baseUrl}/login`, user)
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => {
          this.subject.next(res);
          localStorage.setItem('auth_data_token', JSON.stringify(res));
        }),
        shareReplay(),
        catchError((error: Error) => {
          console.log(error, 'Failed to login'); // and your own error handling service here
        })
      );
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.subject.next(null);
    localStorage.removeItem('auth_data_token');
  }

}

export interface UserModel {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
} // update to match your user model

export type UserSubject = {
  user: UserModel
} | null;
```

So to break it down, this code uses RxJS and will not only store the user details and token in the local storage, it will also emits it by a user observable. So you can now access the user through that observable. You could modify my code to add the token to that observable too. You can access the user's details and token elsewhere in your component by one of a few ways, for example, you could subscribe to the observable:

```js
user$: Observable < {
  user: UserModel
} | null > ;
currentUser: UserModel | undefined

this.subscription = this.user$.subscribe((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.currentUser = user.user;
  }
}
});
```

Or access it through a pipe in your html code with:

```html
(authStoreService.user$ | async)
```

And you could also access it through the local storage:

```html
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth_data_token')!)
```

Again, my code only emits the user's details through the observable, but you could easily modify it to add the token as well.